# I have A RenderFlex overflowed in CustomSwitch

Tags: android, ios, flutter

I have `A RenderFlex overflowed`  in `CustomSwitch` with off status and I put `CustomSwitch` inside `popUp`

[image]

Although in the other case it works properly

[image]

what can I do?

Answer (score 0):

**This is because 'On' character size spacing is less than the 'Off' character spacing.**

simply a three-letter word would take more space (horizontal space/ width) than a two-letter word.

Change the `width` of your `CustomSwitch` that will be able to hold the 'Off' word.
Preferable increase the width by `1px` or more.

---

An Alternative would be increasing the width and giving padding for better UI look.

A fancier way would be using a `AnimatedContainer()` that can toggle between the size for the 'on' word and 'off' word.